# Rendering HTML inside a textarea

Tags: html

If i created the following code

```
<textarea name="ta" id="ta">

<textarea>Blah</textarea>

</textarea>
```

when i view it it won't shown the inside code exact as it and will shown only `<textarea>Blah` and won't shown `</textarea>`

that would be

[image: This will be shown]

and i want it to be

[image: That is what i want to be]

I found it also for `<form></form>` it won't shown `</form>`

Thanks

and i want it to appears as

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must escape the brackets inside of the textarea:

```
<textarea name="ta" id="ta"> 

&lt;textarea&gt;Blah&lt;/textarea&gt; 

</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

The text you are wanting to render is treated as plain HTML and rendered as one. Since you don't have anything in between the tags an empty space is printed.

To fix this you have to encode the <,>,& and - characters with &lt, &gt and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use `&lt;` for the `<` character.

Answer (score 0):

The [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/forms.html) does not allow nesting for `forms` or `textareas`.